# If changing the image size is affect to detect colour object in an image :OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to detect leaves diseases in an image using image processing.But becasue of my loading images are too big and it's not fit in to screen. So I resized my images. Then when I am trying to detect green colour objects in an each and every image, I always getting 0 as a value. Is it possible to affect the resizing an image to this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just do the detection and save the image, and then just view it smaller after the fact? Also how are you resizing the image? Are you sure the detection isn't failing when the image is large too?

Answer (score 1):

If you run this once:

```
cv2.namedWindow("your_win_name",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("your_win_name",your_win_width,your_win_height)
```

Whenever you call `cv2.imshow` with that window name, it will show the whole image in that window. So you don't need to resize it.

```
cv2.imshow("your_win_name",image)
```

If it doesn't detect on full image either, then problem is something else.

Comment: Alternatively, along the same lines, you can resize the resulting mask *after* detection for viewing.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds yeah but this way works for any image size (small or big), but if among those big images there was a small one, your method might resize the image to such a small size that you might not be able to recognize anything in it.

Comment: Indeed. Also if you did resize it before displaying, you'd probably want to use nearest neighbor interpolation for viewing a mask.